# Regex pattern format

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex in the application I am working. My problem here is that i'm not quite familiar with this expression.

```
(?<=.+[\r\n]+.+[\r\n]+)([\s\S]*)
```

I searched for each of the expressions but I can't summarize it.

`[\r\n]+` should match multiple line breaks

`[\s\S]` should be any character

I can't end up making any understanding with this.

**EDIT**

This regex is used with automatically removing some automated texts or signatures from an email body.

```
string newComment = string.IsNullOrEmpty(regexPattern) ? emailBody : new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(emailBody, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Can you provide the context in which this regex is used?

Comment: This regex looks very inefficient to me. I think it's finding the last line which starts with white space, except that it can't be one of the first two lines. But it is hugely over-complicated and suffers from backtracking issues (but not catastrophic backtracking, at least)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that regex will ever work in JavaScript. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds. Even if you somehow manage to get lookbehind support with external libraries, I don't think it would support variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: Actually given that the whitespace is any-or-none, I think this will always match the third line (not the last one; I forgot that look-behinds don't move the cursor)

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry for the confusion. It is being used with a C# code

Comment: @AmalMurali the OP updated the question to mention C#

Comment: @Dave Thank you for that. I tested it now on a separate console app and looks like you are right. It will return anything within the 2 line breaks but after that , it will be truncated.

Comment: Ok, if I were you, I'd figure out what the intent was (which it almost certainly fails to fulfil; if line breaks are \r\n it will match the second line for example) and replace it with something else (probably split the text into an array of lines; no regex needed, unless you choose regex for the splitting token)

Comment: I believe the intent is to remove whitespace from the start of each line from line 3 onwards. If I were writing it, I would split the string and iterate through each relevant line, then join the result back together. Much clearer, faster, and far less likely to mess up in strange ways.